# Laravel relations are not working?

Tags: php, laravel

I have relation with Deposit model but relations are not working.

> error:Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\xamp\htdocs\assets\core\resources\views\user\deposit-history.blade.php)

**View code**

```
<tbody>
        @php $i = 0;@endphp
        @foreach($deposit as $p)
            @php $i++;@endphp
            <tr>
                <td>{{ $i }}</td>
                <td width="10%">{{ date('d-F-Y h:s:i A',strtotime($p->created_at)) }}</td>
                <td><span class="aaaa"><strong>{{ $p->plan->name }}</strong></span></td>
                <td>#{{ $p->deposit_number }}</td>
                <td>{{ $p->amount }} - {{ $basic->currency }}</td>
                <td width="13%">{{ $p->percent }} %</td>
                <td>{{ $p->time }} - times</td>
                <td><span class="aaaa"><strong>{{ $p->compound->name }}</strong></span></td>
                <td>
                    @if($p->status == 0)
                        <span class="label label-secondary"><i class="fa fa-spinner"></i> Running</span>
                    @else
                        <span class="label label-success"><i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Completed</span>
                    @endif

                </td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**Model code**

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Deposit extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'deposits';

    protected $fillable = ['deposit_number','user_id','plan_id','amount','status','percent','time','compound_id'];

    public function plan()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Plan::class,'plan_id');
    }
    public function compound()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Compound::class,'compound_id');
    }
    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class,'user_id');
    }
}
```

Comment: non object?? what object?? show full error and which version of laravel you are using??

Comment: Verify that the relationship exists before outputting. If there should be a related object, verify the keys.

Comment: Get all the foreign keys and primary keys from database then you can use this relationships.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view you have:

`<td><span class="aaaa"><strong>{{ $p->plan->name }}</strong></span></td>`

And this:

`<td><span class="aaaa"><strong>{{ $p->compound->name }}</strong></span></td>`

If two line will work if you always have `$p->plan` and `$p->compound`. But if you don't have(e.g. `null`) `$p->plan` or `$p->compound` it will throw an exception(Trying to get property of non-object).

**So, when will these property be `null`?**

Firstly, you need to make sure that you have `plan_id` and `compound_id` in your `deposits` table. Otherwise, the relational property will return `null`.

Secondly, It can be `null` if the `plan_id` or `compound_id` is empty/null or a value that doesn't exist in `plans` or `compounds` table.

**What is the solution even if it's `null`?**

If you need to show other field even if your `plan` or `compound` is null then you can change the above to line into the following lines:

`<td><span class="aaaa"><strong>{{ isset($p->plan) ? $p->plan->name : '' }}</strong></span></td>`

and

`<td><span class="aaaa"><strong>{{ isset($p->compound) ? $p->compound->name : '' }}</strong></span></td>`